# NPM - path to root of the application

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am developing a NPM package, which needs to require a module from the application root. Think of it as the package requiring a properties module, which is placed in the application root by the user.

How do I get the path to root of the application?

**UPDATE:**

To summarize what I am trying to do, express allows you to do something like this:

```
app.use(express.router(myNPMModule.router));
```

The router function will get `app` as the parameter. The idea is to allow the users to specify the routes in a separate file, and they just need to follow certain conventions like putting their controllers in `/controllers` folder, and my module will be able to dynamically parse the path, and then invoke the correct method in the correct module. I have already got it working, but just realized that if I package it in NPM, I no longer have access to the path of the app, so I can't invoke a controller module's method dynamically.

Comment: You shouldn't do that, instead make the user call the "constructor" (or whatever function you have) with the properties.

Comment: See my comment on the other answer. I am writing a router, and I am expecting the user to follow certain conventions. Like putting his controllers in "controllers/moduleName.js" - and then based on the URL, I will be able to invoke the correct controller and method.

Comment: Just try the npm [rainbow](https://npmjs.org/package/rainbow) which I wrote. It's a router middleware same as your requirement for mapping URL to controllers file paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the user call a function that sets the variables:

```
  myModule.setProps(json)
  OR
  myModule = new MyModule(json)
```

Then the user can require their root config and init your module with it.

Update In response to edited question:

Express allows you to define routes like this:

```
var routes = require('./routes')
app.get('/info', routes.info);

//Routes Module
exports.info = function(req, res) {
  res.render('info', {title: 'Express'})
};
```

I believe this is exactly what you are trying to do. Is it not?

Update 2:

You can find the directory the currently executing script is in using __dirname

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

Comment: I considered that, but I also have another need where I need to be able to dynamically load a user module (e.g. when routing a request to a specific controller). Is there any other way to do this? Can I just assume that my module will be in my node_modules/moduleName/lib folder, and just try to relatively access?

Comment: Dynamically as in the modules can change while the program is running? or Dynamically as is you want to load in config files when the program starts.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. When the user enters a URL, my module will parse the URL (based on say, rails like convention) and invoke the appropriate method of a controller module, whose location will follow a convention.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up taking the `__dirname` approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have same question.

And I can only find this environment variable help:

```
process.env.PWD
```

It would always point to the root of your application path where it running.

Comment: Gives me undefined value... -1

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
var path = require('path');
console.log(path.dirname(module.parent.filename));
```